# How to get rows value as header with summary information dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have a table called EMPLOYEE where i am having columns as EMP_NAME,EMP_DOJ (Date of join) like as shown below.

```
EMP_NAME|EMP_DOJ  
Ramesh  |10-jan-2017  
Sandeep |09-jan-2017  
Bhaskar |11-feb-2017  
Jyoti   |12-mar-2017  
Rohan   |12-mar-2017  
Kadali  |11-feb-2018  
Kumari  |12-mar-2018  
Salvi   |12-mar-2018
```

My requirement is to get month and year wise employees joined count and month and year should be as a header as shown below.

```
JAN17_COUNT|FEB17_COUNT|MAR17_COUNT|FEB18_COUNT|MAR18_COUNT  
2          |1          |2          |1          |2
```

I tried with below query where i user month and year value manually in `PIVOT` like JAN17,FEB17.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  ( SELECT TO_CHAR(EMP_DOJ,'MONYY') MONTHYEAR FROM EMPLOYEE ) 
PIVOT ( COUNT(1) CNT FOR MONTHYEAR IN ('JAN17','FEB17') );
```

In real time scenario, I want to get all the months and years combination data with out specifying manually in `PIVOT`

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a dynamic `CURSOR` that uses the `PIVOT` values to be used in the `IN` clause created dynamically with `LISTAGG`, and then use `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` ( Oracle12c +)  or `PRINT` statement to return the output of the cursor.

```
DECLARE
v_in_args VARCHAR2(4000);
cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG('''' || doj || '''  AS  ' 
                      || doj || '_COUNT', ', ') WITHIN
GROUP (
        ORDER BY TO_DATE(doj,'MONYY')
        ) INTO  v_in_args
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(EMP_DOJ, 'MONYY') AS doj
      FROM EMPLOYEE
    );

OPEN cur FOR 'SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT EMP_NAME
        ,TO_CHAR(EMP_DOJ, ''MONYY'') AS DOJ
    FROM EMPLOYEE ORDER BY EMP_DOJ
    )
PIVOT(COUNT(EMP_NAME) FOR DOJ IN ( '||v_in_args||'))';

DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(cur);
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

ResultSet #1

JAN17_COUNT FEB17_COUNT MAR17_COUNT FEB18_COUNT MAR18_COUNT
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
          2           1           2           1           2
```

In oracle 11g,  you may use the same block along with a ref cursor bind variable.It works in SQL* Plus or in SQL developer,Toad when run as script.

```
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR
DECLARE
.. --declaring cursor not needed.
..
OPEN :cur FOR ...
.. 
..  --can't use DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT
END;
/

PRINT x; -- This will give you the result.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you download "AntonsPivoting.zip" in the "Resources" section on the [Dynamic SQL Pivoting – Stealing Anton’s Thunder](https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/) page by Lucas Jellema and run the `pivotFun.sql` in your schema, it'll create some objects, along with the PIVOT function which allows you to dynamically do what you're about to.

For example:

```
SQL> select * from
  2  table(
  3    pivot('select hd, cnt
  4            from (select to_char(hiredate, ''yyyy.mm'') hd, count(*) cnt
  5                  from emp group by to_char(hiredate, ''yyyy.mm''))'
  6         )
  7       );

   1980.12    1981.02    1981.04    1981.05    1981.06    1981.09    1981.11    1981.12

---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------

         1          2          1          1          1          2          1          2
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. as suggested i have downloaded pivotfun.sql and executed in my schema and i formed query like SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
(
PIVOT('SELECT HD, CNT
          FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(EMP_DOJ, ''YYYY.MM'') HD, COUNT(*) CNT
                FROM EMPTBL GROUP BY TO_CHAR(EMP_DOJ, ''YYYY.MM''))'
       )
);  i am getting error like ora-29913: error in executing ODCITABLEDESCRIBE callout. Please help.

Comment: When you ran pivotFun.sql, did it complete successfully? It should create a type, type body and a function.

Comment: When i executed sql file three types has been created like 1.type PivotImpl object
2.type body PivotImpl
3.fucntion pivot

Comment: So, that was OK. As you can see, I ran that query and everything was just fine, no errors. Which database version do you use?

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
CORE 12.1.0.2.0 Production
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

Comment: Hm, I'm on 11gR2; I, somehow, doubt that your "higher" version causes problems. Sorry, I wouldn't know what is the problem. I've checked the author's page and saw that people have the same issue. One of them says that he has had a reserved word (or keyword) among column list to be returned, but - you don't (HD, CNT, EMP_DOJ - none of these are suspicious) so, unfortunately, I have no idea what might be going on.